# How do you navigate to a new page in a metro app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

trying to write a metro app in C# right now. Ran into a problem while trying to navigate to a new page.

```
<HyperLinkButton NavigateUri="foo.xaml"/>
```

doesn't work, as the NavigateUri field doesn't exist.
The Windows.Navigate namespace isn't available either, so no luck there. What's the proper way to go to a new page in my app in metro?

Comment: Is this WPF?  If so, please add the tag (I decided I wasn't sure so I removed my edit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can handle the Button control's Click event (in fact, you can use all events with the following code) because Metro's HyperLink button only inherits the ButtonBase class without any special properties or events, such as NavigateUri.

If you want to navigate to another page in your metro app, add a frame in the `.xaml` page and put this code in the button's event handler:

`this.Frame.Navigate("VideoStoryCreator.ComposePage");`

Comment: `WinJS.Navigation.navigate` if you're using js

Comment: By using WinJS.Navigation.navigate am not able to navigate to other page like other html?can you elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways of Navigating to another page -

- Client app way ->

You'll implement this in click event -

```
var page = new PageName();
Window.Current.Content = page;
```

---

- Similar to Silverlight Navigation

If you are using Frame/Page Navigation then you can do it like this -

Create a shell page (master page) with the  element declared. Then instead of creating new pages with  create . 
The easiest way to do this is to replace UserControl with Page

This is nicely explained in this tutorial - 
http://www.markermetro.com/2011/11/technical/windows-8-metro-style-apps-implementing-navigation-with-xaml/

Hope it helps!

Regards,
Bhavik

Comment: And that's the great answer that describes masterpage-like navigation. The link you posted was extremely helpful. All the bullshit-like navigation shown in metro-templates should be banned (see AppBar example on the msdn). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Handle the Click event on the button and then call the Navigate method on your Frame

Answer (score -1):

just type the following code in your click event

```
this->Frame->Navigate(TargetPageName::typeid,this);
```